# Why is this happening? Js calculations

Tags: javascript, calculator

So,im trying to build simple calc and i cant get it to work as simple as it may and be  and i have no idea.
When adding the values the only the salary - rent work after the are getting
concatenated example:9000 -100 = 8900 fine but after adding something else im getting 8900 - 100 = 8900100

```
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click',calculateTaxes);

// calculateTaxes
function calculateTaxes(e){
//UI vars
const sal   = document.querySelector('#salary');
const sel   = document.querySelector('#selection');
const rent  = document.querySelector('#rent');
const travel  = document.querySelector('#travel');
const groce  = document.querySelector('#groce');
const elSe = document.querySelector('#else');
const btn  = document.querySelector('#btn');
let final;

final = sal.value - (rent.value+travel.value+groce.value+elSe.value)

}
```

Comment: please add html

Comment: what exactly is the problem, can your please specify

Comment: Why is _what_ happening?

Answer (score 0):

You may have the input textbox as `text` so if that is so you need to parse the input value to integers before calculation. Something like this:

```
// calculateTaxes
function calculateTaxes(e){
 //UI vars
 const sal   = document.querySelector('#salary');
 const sel   = document.querySelector('#selection');
 const rent  = document.querySelector('#rent');
 const travel  = document.querySelector('#travel');
 const groce  = document.querySelector('#groce');
 const elSe = document.querySelector('#else');
 const btn  = document.querySelector('#btn');
 let final;

 final = parseInt(sal.value) - (parseInt(rent.value) + parseInt(travel.value) + parseInt(groce.value) + parseInt(elSe.value));
}
```

Comment: Thnx but i already tried to parse it and im getting NaN

Comment: You should not be getting `NaN` if you parsed it.